# React-select-async-paginate options async function making generic

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to make this function generic. so that to avoid condition in response. passing key through parameters is an option but I am not sure how can i use it?

```
  async function loadOptions(search: string, loadedOptions: any, { page }: AdditionalProps) {
    const response: any = await networkRequest(() =>
      httpClient.get(
        url.replace(":page", page.toString()).replace(":keyword", search),
      ),
    );
    return {
      options: response?.data?.map((item: ItemProps) => ({
        label: url.includes("/employees") ? `${item?.first_name} ${item?.last_name}` : item?.name,
        value: item?.id,
      })),
      hasMore: response?.meta?.last_page > page,
      additional: {
        page: page + 1,
      },
    };
  }

  return loadOptions;
};
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Are you sure that response if of shape `{data: ItemProps[], meta: {last_page: number}}`? Do you want to avoid optional chaining?

Comment: Can u explain me what is optional chaining?